# Subplots won't display together + griddata() returning "nan" values

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, interpolation, subplot

I have a 9x9 matrix in which I know 8 values, at the positions contained in array *points*, with corresponding values in array *values*. I want to interpolate the unknown values and paste the result on a 200x200 image.

I'm a beginner at python and I'm struggling with the following:

1. My subplots won't display together. Subplot(121) and subplot(122) should create a single image with both plots next to each other (horizontally), but instead I always get two separate images. What am I doing wrong, and why?
2. The code below is my attempt at using griddata() to interpolate the known values on a 200x200 grid. The result, *grid_z*, is however completely filled with *nan* values, and I don't understand why or how I can solve this.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X, Y = np.mgrid[0:1:200j, 0:1:200j]

points = np.array([(3, 8),(5, 8),(4, 6),(4, 4),(2, 4),(6, 4),(3, 0),(5, 0)])
values =  [ 1.82907198,  1.69794981,  1.30089053, -0.00452952,  2.32777365,  0.69508469,  2.06540834,  2.1184028 ]


grid_z = griddata(points, values, (X, Y), method='cubic')

plt.figure

plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot(points[:,0], points[:,1], 'ro', markersize=10)
plt.xlim(0, 8)
plt.ylim(0, 8)
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.title('Original')

plt.subplots(122)
plt.imshow(grid_z.T, extent=(0,8,0,8), origin='lower')
plt.title('Cubic')
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(6, 6)
plt.show()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I've consulted dozens of similar posts online but am unable to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work with subplots you need to use Matplotlib's object-oriented approach (more info [here](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/)).

Regarding `grid_z` containing NaN values, it happens because you selected the wrong discretization domain. In the code below I used `X, Y = np.mgrid[2:6:200j, 0:8:200j]`: here x will start from 2 and goes to 6, and y will go from 0 to 8. Note that this range covers the known points. Outside of these known points you will get Nan.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize

X, Y = np.mgrid[2:6:200j, 0:8:200j]

points = np.array([(3, 8),(5, 8),(4, 6),(4, 4),(2, 4),(6, 4),(3, 0),(5, 0)])
values =  np.array([ 1.82907198,  1.69794981,  1.30089053, -0.00452952,  2.32777365,  0.69508469,  2.06540834,  2.1184028 ])

grid_z = griddata(points, values, (X, Y), method='linear')

f, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, tight_layout=True)

cmap = "jet"
norm = Normalize(vmin=values.min(), vmax=values.max())
scatter = axs[0].scatter(points[:,0], points[:,1], c=values, norm=norm, cmap=cmap)
axs[0].set_xlim(0, 8)
axs[0].set_ylim(0, 8)
axs[0].set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
axs[0].set_title('Original')

axs[1].imshow(grid_z.T, extent=(0,8,0,8), origin='lower', cmap=cmap)
axs[1].set_title('Cubic')

f.colorbar(scatter)
f.axes[2].set_ylabel("values")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: How could I have missed that in np.mgrid... It solved the problem, thanks so much!

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer as the solution to your question.